# wpf stylings not working on initial startup

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styling

I'm writing a wpf application and this issue is escaping me.

When I launch my app I have a style set all of the buttons to Cursor="Hand". For some reason, only some of the buttons have this behavior and some don't. However after I make a single click *anywhere* on my computer, *all* of the buttons have Hand behavior upon hover as expected.

There isn't much code to post.

```
<Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
```

Edit: This appears to be the case for all styling on some of the buttons, until the first click occurs.

Comment: Can you tell us where you put that style?

Comment: It's being applied to each button. `Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}"`

Comment: It is set on each button.